# why does a simulator returns uagent as ipad even for iphone simulation?

Tags: javascript, xcode

I tried to run this following code

```
var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
 if (uagent.search("iphone") > -1)
     alert("true");
 else
      alert(uagent);
```

[image: output i got]

and getting above output, **even when i choose iphone for simulation**

why does this happens?

Comment: Your if/else statements do the same thing?

Comment: i was just editing randomly to take a look at what uagent holds. ! this is not what i use  ! .!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a very long story very short:

User agent strings are problematic.

Making assumptions based on the user agent string is even more so.

[Mozilla has a reasonably comprehensive article on it here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)